# Why the set function not work in my code?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, properties

I used the model with byte[] attribute that should be convert to short[] before used.

I add two properties to convert byte[] to short[] using get property and its work well. 
my problem is when i try to use Set property to do the opposite and set byte[] array when changing the short[] my code not work and when i debug the code it doesn't call the Set Function at all.

```
public class TestModel
{
   public byte[] Data { get; set; } // The original data
   private short[] _DataConverted { get; set; }
   public short[] DataConvert
   {
    get => _DataConverted ?? (_DataConverted = Data.GetShiftShort());
    set
    {
     Data = value.GetShiftByteFShort();
     _DataConverted = value;
    }
   }
}

public void Main()
{
  TestModel modal =new TestModel()
  {
   Data = new byte[] {0,1,0,2,0,3}
  };
  modal.DataConvert[0] ++;
  modal.DataConvert[1] +=1;
  modal.DataConvert[2] = modal.DataConvert[2] + 1 ;
}
```

And the result is:

_DataConverted {2,3,4}

DataConvert {2,3,4}

But the Data don't change {0,1,0,2,0,3}

Comment: But you don't set/assign the DataConvert property in your code. So of course the `set` accessor of DataConvert is not called. `set` accessor of a property is only invoked if some value is assigned to the property. (By the way, `_DataConverted` should just be a field, not a property, as its sole purpose seems to be the backing field for the `DataConvert` property)

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand your answer clearly. can you please modify my code or provide me more information about your answer?

Comment: Just a suggestion (i don't mind if you ignore it). I would not use properties to do the data conversion. Rather implement methods that you call to convert from one array type to the other, like for example `byte[] ConvertShortDataToByteData(short[])` and `short[] ConvertByteDataToShort(byte[])`.

Comment: Your code is not assigning something to the `DataConvert` property. Thus, the `set` accessor is not being called. If you don't understand this, it would perhaps be time well spend looking into some guide/tutorial about .NET properties (like for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: so the problem is changing the array contents doesn't call the set accessory of the it's parents. Is there any way to operate the reverse operation, and after changing the array's contents, this change is also made in the original data?

Comment: There are of course different ways to skin your cat. The easiest approach (and least error-prone, i guess), is to just stick with one array type that you use for keeping the data (for example the byte[] array). Whenever some part of your code needs the data in a different representation (say short[]), let it grab the byte[] array and do the conversion by calling a method (as i already suggested). If a part of your program needs to convert some data back and store it as a byte[] array, again create an appropriate conversion method. Don't try to be too clever with your properties ;-)

Comment: An alternative would be to replace the arrays with some other _observable_ collection type that would allow your code to observe when some element in the collection is being added/removed/replaced. But this would then require to wire up and handle the collection change notification events correctly, which is not as easy (and more likely to mess up) compared to the approach of letting your code just use conversion methods. And it is not easy to get right, as a naiive implementation of this approach could quickly blow up in your face when your app is multi-threaded. (like any GUI-based app)